# Same property with diferent methods on UIView and it's subclasses

Tags: swift, uiview, swift-protocols

So the requirement is to have a property on all UIView subclasses like `myView.property`. Than for many subclasses there would be some specific functionality, like lets say for `UILabel` and all it's subclasses would have only label specific stuff. Same for other elements ...

So I really need to be able to do following:

```
MyView.property.methodSharedByAllUIViewSubclasses
MyImageView.property.someImageViewSpecificMethod
MyLabel.property.onlyLabelSpecificMethod
```

Any help on how to design for this kind of situation in Swift will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I would like to use protocols and protocol extensions to achieve this ...

Comment: I don't get what you think is supposed to happen. Consider UILabel. It is LabelExtendable, which is empty but conforms to Extendable which is empty. So UILabel itself is totally unaffected, except insofar as it inherits from UIView. UIView does now have a `lui` property: `let lab = UILabel(); let lui = lab.lui` does compile. What else is supposed to happen? Your question seems to talk of a property called `property` but there isn't one in your code.

Comment: Also you are doing something very mysterious with typealias.

Comment: Well, obviously the code doesn’t work, I just hoped it would illustrate what I am trying to achive, the three lines at the end are the wishful result

Comment: What functionality are you trying to enable?

Comment: "I just hoped it would illustrate what I am trying to achive" Don't make us guess. _Tell_ us what you are trying to achieve! Pretty silly to throw away 50 points of rep on a bounty that can't get you any help because no one knows what would constitute helping. What's the overall goal here? What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: I agree with @matt please state in your question **what you want to happen**

Comment: so I deleted what I had and the requirement is that's left.

Comment: Does the `property` need to be a stored property? If so, you are going to need to use Objective-C associated properties to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Honestly, I think that this question is confusing everyone because what you want seems like poor design in general. Can you give us more of an understanding of what you are actually trying to achieve? It is likely that creating this `property` isn't the best way to go about it.

Comment: Honestly, I think I actually do know what I am trying to achieve ... imagine SnapKit's snp but with different methods on each basic view type (view, label, image, button, etc) at this moment I got prefix_mymethod everywhere and I believe that using protocols there will be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Property<T> {
    let property: T

    init(_ obj: T) {
        property = obj
    }
}

protocol PropertyDSL {
    associatedtype DSL
    var property: Property<DSL> { get set }
}

extension PropertyDSL {
    var property: Property<Self> {
        get {
            return Property(self)
        }
        set { }
    }
}

extension UIView: PropertyDSL {}

extension Property where T: UIView {
    func methodSharedByAllUIViewSubclasses() {
    }
}

extension Property where T: UIImageView {
    func someImageViewSpecificMethod() {
    }
}

extension Property where T: UILabel {
    func onlyLabelSpecificMethod() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!!  . This is exactly what @Ondrej asked for , don't know why he haven't marked it as accepted answer yet .

Answer (score 0):

you can override the existing variable/function in every subclass

```
class MyView: UIView {

   var property: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        } set {

        }
    }
    func propertyFunction () {
        //methodSharedByAllUIViewSubclasses
    }
}


class MyImageView: MyView {

   override var property: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        } set {

        }
    }
    override func propertyFunction () {
        //someImageViewSpecificMethod
    }
}

class MyLabel: MyView {

   override var property: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        } set {

        }
    }
    override func propertyFunction () {
        //onlyLabelSpecificMethod
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a Swiftier solution using Protocols as the tag states ... :(

Answer (score -1):

In swift 3 you can create extension like shown in below code snippet and add some additional properties to standard classes and use it in multiple places as per your needs.

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
}
```

The above mentioned extension will allow you add cornerRadius to any of your UIView or its subclasses which inherits UIView like UIImageView.

Below is the result of above code snipped:

[image]

I hope this will help you to achieve what you want.